# Testing javascript apply method with sinon

Tags: javascript, sinon

How can I test `Function.prototype.apply` method on this code?

```
var yoGen = require('yeoman-generator');

exports.method = function () {

    yoBen.Base.apply(this, arguments);

};
```

How can I assert that apply was called with the right arguments on the right module? I try like this but fail:

```
var apply = sinon.stub(yoGen.Base,'apply');
testingModule.method();
sinon.assert.calledWith(apply,testingModule,{});
```

The error of assert is:

```
apply({ ... content of testingModule ... }) != { ... content of testingModule ... }
```

Comment: What is the module supposed to do? Is it a function that returns something?

Comment: @staypuftman I have updated question... btw its function...

Answer (score 0):

`Function.prototype.apply` is just a short-hand to loop an object through a function. MDN shows a [pretty good example to follow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];

// using Math.min/Math.max apply
var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers); 
// This about equal to Math.max(numbers[0], ...)
// or Math.max(5, 6, ...)
```

In your example, it's not 100% clear what you `yoBen` function does but you'd be looping through your `arguments` and could just output the result like this:

```
// Put apply into a variable     
var results = yoBen.Base.apply(this, arguments);

// Just output the results and see what happened
console.log(results);
```

Comment: The `JSON.stringify(testingModule)` after executing the method is  `apply({ ... content of testingModule ... })`, how the hell can I test this?

Comment: Go back a step - what does `console.log(apply);` output.

Comment: The apply is native `Function.prototype.apply`. So apply output is `apply is not defined`.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't follow what you are doing in this JS. I either need a bunch more context or code to make sense of this.